# Get rid of noise while using recv in C++

Tags: c++, tcp

I am receiving data following a certain format over a TCP server by serializing them.
the class of the object:

```cpp
class Command {
private:

    char letter;
    int x;
    int y;
    std::string button;

public:
    Command(char _letter, int _x, int _y, std::string _button) {
        letter = _letter;
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        button = _button;
    }

    Command(std::string serializedCmd)
    {
        
        size_t delimPos = 0;
        std::vector<std::string> parts;
        while ((delimPos = serializedCmd.find(SERIALIZE_DELIM)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            parts.push_back(serializedCmd.substr(0, delimPos));
            serializedCmd.erase(0, delimPos + 1);
        }

        if (parts.empty()) {
            this->letter = '$';
            this->x = -1;
            this->y = -1;
            this->button = "nan";
            return;
        }

        this->letter = (char)atoi(parts.at(0).data());
        this->x = atoi(parts.at(1).data());
        this->y = atoi(parts.at(2).data());
        this->button = parts.at(3);
    }

    Command() {}
    ~Command() {}

    std::string serialize()
    {
        return std::to_string(letter) + SERIALIZE_DELIM + std::to_string(x) + SERIALIZE_DELIM + std::to_string(y) + SERIALIZE_DELIM + button + SERIALIZE_DELIM;
    }

    char getLetter() { return letter; }
    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return y; }
    std::string getButton() { return button; }

    bool isEmpty() {
        return((this->letter == '$') && (this->x == -1) && (this->y == -1) && (this->button == "nan"));
    }

    void printCommand() {
        std::cout << "letter: " << letter << std::endl;
        std::cout << "x     : " << x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "y     : " << y << std::endl;
        std::cout << "button: " << button << std::endl;
        std::cout << "================" << std::endl;
    }

};
```

The data after being DeSerialized at the clients end follows this format:

```
||{key}|{x}|{y}|{button}||
```

```
Example: ||$|20|40|nan||
```

The problem is that when using `recv` to get the data, it seems that I'm picking up some noise around the command.

Example:

```
Sending:
||$|301|386|nan||
```

```
Reciving:
(¿ⁿ8T√|301|386|╠╠↕▼
```

The command is there although it's crowded with noise for some reason.
The code I'm using to receive the data:

```cpp
char buf[4096];

    Command c;
    std::string commandTemp = "";
    while (true) {
        memset(buf, '\0', 4096);
        const int size = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

        std::string s(buf,size);
        std::cout << s << std::endl; 


        buf[size] = 0;
        commandTemp = buf;

        if (!commandTemp.empty()) {
            
            try {
                c = Command(commandTemp);   
                exe(c);  //executes command (unrelated)
            }
            catch (const std::exception& err) {
                std::cout << "Couldn't execute!!!!!!!!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error empty command!\n";
        }
    }
```

If I am missing any information I will happily provide it.
Can someone maybe tell what the problem is?

Comment: Here you carefully trim the buffer to the actually-received data: `std::string s(buf,size);`   But then you process the untrimmed buffer: `commandTemp = buf;` :(  Get rid of `commandTemp` and use `s`, the trimmed data.

Comment: Also be sure to check for a negative return value from `recv` which indicates an error.

Comment: Output or inspect the raw data __as hex__ (a) just before the `send` and (b) immediately after the `recv`.

Comment: And since you've swapped the buffers on receive and didn't print with you process, I suggest you use Wireshark to inspect the data actually sent through the connection, just in case you didn't send what you print.

Comment: @BenVoigt I swapped ```commandTemp = buf;``` to ```commandTemp = s;```
but the data is still noisey. The revc function works fine since I'm constantly getting those bad commands that correspond to what I'm sending.

Comment: @Guyzvi -- 1) Do not use functions that use null-terminators to mark the end of string data.  For example, the `std::string` constructor you were using does just this, and you don't want that.  2) Do not artificially stick null bytes into the data you retrieved, and especially if the data already may contain null bytes -- you do that here: `buf[size] = 0;`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That makes sense, how would I go about solving the noise problem after cleaning up the things you mentioned?

Comment: `std::cout << s << std::endl; ` -- I suggest you change this to `std::cout.write(buf, size); std::cout << std::endl;`.  You are introducing a level of "indirection" by storing the data in a `std::string`.  Also, are you using output routines to see what the data is that you retrieved?  You should be using a debugger, or at the very least, output the data as hex values, not as characters.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: `s` was constructed correctly with an explicit size parameter.  `commandTemp = buf;` was the problematic `std::string` assignment, which he already removed at my suggestion.  `commandTemp = s;` is safe, as copying from a counted string doesn't rely on NUL characters.

Comment: The deserialize `Command` constructor is clearly buggy, because it only tests if the vector length is at least `1`, but reads up to index `3`.  Change `if (parts.empty())` to `if (parts.size() < 4)`

Comment: And don't use `atoi()`, it has undefined behavior on some input.  Use `strtol()` which fails safely instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop on the recv till you get the entire message

This may not be the immediate cause of you problem but you will hit it eventually.

TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol. All that TCP guarantees is that the bytes you send are received once and in order. But you might send one 100 byte message and receive 20 5 byte messages. You will say "but it works now", true if on the same machine or the messages are small but not true with larger message over a real netwrok so you must do this

```
char buf[4096];
Command c;
std::string commandTemp = "";
while (true) {

    memset(buf, '\0', 4096);
    int offset = 0;
    int len = ??;
    while(len > 0){
    
      const int size = recv(sock, buf + offset, sizeof(buf) - offset, 0);
      if (size == 0)
          break; // record that we got incomplete message
      offset += size;
      len -= size;
    }  
 ....
```

Note that you need to know the length in advance too. So either send fixed length message or prepend a fixed size length to each message and read that first

Comment: But that IS the message but with noise around it

Comment: @Guyzvi TCP has no concept of messages, only bytes.  There is no 1:1 relationship between `send()` and `recv()`. Both functions can return fewer bytes sent/received than requested. You can get messages split up between multiple packets, and multiple messages merged in a single packet. You have to handle message boundaries in your own code, and call both functions in a loop until each message is sent/received in full.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How can I "loop" the recv function? Do you mean appending the data to a string until it fits my format?

Comment: @Guyzvi basically, yes.  Append each received buffer to your string, and then extract only complete messages from the string until there are none left. Leave behind any incomplete messages for subsequent reads to finish.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Will the recv function know when the packet is over or will I need to check when it's done with a single command?

Comment: @Guyzvi I answered that in my previous comments. `recv()` has no concept of your messages, only raw bytes.  So keep reading and gathering the bytes into your own buffer, and process only complete messages from that buffer as needed.

Comment: @Guyzvi see edited message